# Array.prototype.slice weird behaviour

Tags: javascript

Consider this piece of code, with console output at the end of each line:

```
function whatever() {
  console.log(arguments) // { '0': 1, '1': 2, '2': 3, '3': 4, '4': 5 }
  console.log(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)) // [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
  console.log(Array.prototype.slice.call({ '0': 1, '1': 2, '2': 3, '3': 4, '4': 5 })) // []
}

whatever(1,2,3,4,5)
```

Why is it that the third `console.log` outputs an empty array?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because in order for `Array.prototype.slice` to work, you need to pass an array-like object. And in order for an object to fit that category, it needs a `length` property, which your object doesn't have. Try this:

```
var arr = { '0': 1, '1': 2, '2': 3, '3': 4, '4': 5 };
arr.length = 5;
var res = Array.prototype.slice.call(arr);
console.log(res);
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/UcvHP/)**

Comment: Instead of assigning length in such way, maybe would be better if you get enumerable keys length `arr.length = Object.keys(arr).length`

Comment: @Givi I agree. But to be even closer to the actual behavior of an array, you would have to set the `length` property to the highest numerical key plus one. `arr.length = Object.keys(arr).filter(function(item){return /^[0-9]+$/.test(item);}).sort(function(a,b){return b-a})[0] + 1;`. Anyway, it was just an example to show that it works, as long as you have the `length` property set correctly :)

Comment: Beautiful solution, but sort is useless in that case, I think so ;)
and `sort(...)[0] + 1`; is same as "4" + 1 that equals 41. And maybe you should get length after filtering, `filter(...).length`, and even array-like object is not sorted while slicing it'll be sorted as it should ;) And even in object is other properties like `"someProperty" : "some value"`, they will not be added while slicing.

Comment: @Givi You're right, you need to convert the key to a number before adding 1. I missed that. But you still would have to sort it I think, since you don't want the number of keys but the highest key. If you have the keys 0,1,3 you want the length to be 4, as it would be in a real array. And yes, non-numerical properties will not be added, when you silce it. But you calculate the length before you slice and therefore you have to filter them out.

Answer (score 2):

As @basilikum described, this is because `.length` is required in order to use `.slice()`. To understand *why* it's required, imagine that you were writing your own version of `Array.prototype.slice()` after reading the MDN docs:

---

#### Syntax

```
Array.slice(begin[, end])
```

#### Parameters

**`begin`**

Zero-based index at which to begin extraction.

As a negative index, `begin` indicates an offset from the end of the sequence. `slice(-2)` extracts the second-to-last element and the last element in the sequence.

**`end`**

Zero-based index at which to end extraction. `slice` extracts up to but not including `end`.

`slice(1,4)` extracts the second element through the fourth element (elements indexed 1, 2, and 3).

As a negative index, `end` indicates an offset from the end of the sequence. `slice(2,-1)` extracts the third element through the second-to-last element in the sequence.

If `end` is omitted, `slice` extracts to the end of the sequence.

---

To handle all those cases and a few more not listed, your code would have to be something along these lines (this may have bugs but should be close):

```
Array.prototype.myslice = function( begin, end ) {
    // Use array length or 0 if missing
    var length = this.length || 0;
    // Handle missing begin
    if( begin === undefined ) begin = 0;
    // Handle negative begin, offset from array length
    if( begin < 0 ) begin = length + begin;
    // But make sure that didn't put it less than 0
    if( begin < 0 ) begin = 0;
    // Handle missing end or end too long
    if( end === undefined  ||  end > length ) end = length;
    // Handle negative end (don't have to worry about < 0)
    if( end < 0 ) end = length + end;
    // Now copy the elements and return resulting array
    var result = [];
    for( var i = begin;  i < end;  ++i )
        result.push( this[i] );
    return result;
};
```

That's why `.slice()` requires `this.length`—you wouldn't be able to write the function without it.

Answer (score 0):

As much as i have knowledge

Argument is a variable of object type which we can use to get entry for every argument passed to a method

for example if we use this

```
whatever(a,b,c)
```

argument will return some thing like `0:a ,1:b ,2:c`

and slice method is used to slice an array from a starting point to end point like

```
var myarray=["1","2","3","4"];
myarray.slice(2,3);
```

will return 3 and 4 as they exist on index 2 and 3

so if u want to use slice on your arguments just define it like `slice(startindex,endindex);`

just an edit slice.call is used to convert an array type to another array type data structure and in your case while passing arguments as it is a known type for javascript engine it considers it as an array type and simply converts it but hardcoding an array doesn't seems to work (just a thought).